# Remove the background picture from the title page Latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex, beamer

I put a background picture to all my slides. However, I want to remove that picture from the only first page and keep the background for the rest of the slides. The following code is how I put that picture to all slides.

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[opacity=0.1, at=(current page.center)] {
   \includegraphics[height=150,width=150]{pic.png}};
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[opacity=0.1, at=(current page.center)] {
   \includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
}

\begin{document}
    
{
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame}   
  
\end{document}
```